# How to use VBA to automate clicking of URLs?

Tags: excel, vba

I have a list in Excel of thousands of project IDs. I need the VBA code to insert the project ID into a preset, internal HTML link and "click" the link (listed below as "example.com"). Clicking the HTML link into a browser initiates an automatic download of files. I have copied my code below but continue getting various errors. Appreciate any thoughts on this.

```
Sub followWebsiteLink()

Dim ie As InternetExplorer

Dim html As HTMLDocument

Dim Link As String

Dim Data As Worksheet

Dim startRow, endRow As Integer

Set Data = Sheets("Sheet1")

startRow = 34

endRow = 3574

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Set ie = New InternetExplorer

ie.Visible = True

With Data

    For i = startRow To endRow

        Link = "https://www.example.com/" & .Range("C" & i).Value

        Link.Click

        startRow = startRow + 1

    Next i

End With

End Sub
```

Comment: A `String` has no `Click` method, so this will not even compile. (You are looking for the `Navigate` method of IE.) As a general advice: do not go down this path. IE is deprecated, and even if you get the code to technically work, navigating to >3000 URLs and expecting a file download is bound to fail. Have a look at this link, it may give you a staring point: http://www.excelvbasolutions.com/2014/09/download-file-from-url-using-vba.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this ...

```
Option Explicit

Private Declare Function ShellExecute Lib "shell32.dll" Alias "ShellExecuteA" ( _
  ByVal hWnd As Long, _
  ByVal Operation As String, _
  ByVal Filename As String, _
  Optional ByVal Parameters As String, _
  Optional ByVal Directory As String, _
  Optional ByVal WindowStyle As Long = vbMinimizedFocus) As Long

Public Sub OpenUrl()
    Dim lngSuccess As Long
    lngSuccess = ShellExecute(0, "Open", "https://www.google.com")
End Sub
```

... adapt it to your code accordingly.